# ojdbc7 using addBatch method insert wrong data into table

Tags: java, jdbc, ojdbc

There is a link for [oracle batch](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjdbc/performance-extensions.html#GUID-EB4B2280-70DF-4433-8B4A-59DD3108DB41), I use it in a project, like below:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = 
        conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO user VALUES(?, ?)");

pstmt.setInt(1, 2);
pstmt.setString(2, "a");
pstmt.addBatch();

pstmt.setInt(1, 3);
//pstmt.setString(2, "b");
pstmt.addBatch();
```

The table has two fields, id and name. I don't set name the second time, but in the table there are still two records and names are both 'a'.

ojdbc version

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
  <version>12.1.0.2</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Is there anything wrong in my usage, or just ojdbc has a defect? Should I align the parameter before using the ojbdc batching?

Comment: The `7` in `ojdbc7` means it targets Java 7. Are you really still using Java 7? If not, you may want to upgrade to a different variant (and version) of the Oracle JDBC driver.

Comment: Yes still use Java7 ,and not plan to upgrade recently.

Comment: Unless you're paying Azul, that means you're using an unsupported version of Java which no longer receives security updates. You might want to consider that a big business liability.

Answer (score 3):

`a` is still set from the first record. You could do

```
pstmt.clearParameters();
```

before setting values for the 2<sup>nd</sup> record

Answer (score 3):

This is the expected and correct behaviour. Parameters values that you don't set again between `addBatch` or `execute` methods retain their values, and will be used on the next `addBatch` or `execute` call.

This is specified in section 13.2.2 *Setting Parameters* of the [JDBC 4.3 specification](https://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jdbc-4_3-mrel3-spec/index.html):

> The values set for the parameter markers of a `PreparedStatement`
> object are not reset when it is executed. The method `clearParameters`
> can be called to explicitly clear the values that have been set.
> Setting a parameter with a different value will replace the previous
> value with the new one.

(This rule also applies for `addBatch`, though this is not explicitly specified. Be aware, there is an exception to this rule for `InputStream`- and `Reader`-based parameters defined later.)

As Reimeus says in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77402298/466862), if you don't want that, you'll need to call `clearParameters()` after adding to the batch (or executing).